# PMOS current mirror acting wonky in Simscape

Tags: integrated-circuit, pmos, current-mirror

I am trying to model a current mirror, seen below, solely built upon PMOS. This should not be a hard task because the theory and implementation are straightforward.

What I do get when I model it in Simscape is the graph(s) below.

We can see the current source being constant, the blue line, and the yellow spiking in both positive and negative directions before settling to the mirrored value.

- What are those spikes about?
- What have I missed and is it possible to reduce it?

Current mirror circuit:

[image: Current mirror circuit]

Picture 1, zoomed in, of the response:

[image: Picture 1, zoomed in, of the response]

Picture 2, emphasis on the positive spike of the response:

[image: Picture 2, emphasize on the positive spike, of the response]

Picture 3, emphasis on the whole response showing the negative spike:

[image: Picture 3, emphasize on the whole response showing the negative spike.]

Comment: What are the yellow lines representing?

Answer (score 1):

*This answer assumes that the yellow lines represent the current of the right PMOS. See my comment on the question.*

Your circuit works as you want. The reason for that spike is due to the fact that this circuit works too fast. You need to slow down the drive of the right PMOS. This can be done by using a resistor between the two gates of the PMOS. The higher the resistance, the slower this circuit will function. With simulations, you can find a value that works for you. The short-circuit between the gate and the drain of the left MOSFET needs to be directly connected.

The reason a resistor works is that you are using a PMOS. A PMOS is a type of MOSFET. This means that the gate of the PMOS is capacitive. By using a resistor, you slow down the charging of the capacitor at the gate of the PMOS. Hence, the spike will be reduced.

If you don't want to use a resistor, you can look for MOSFET's with low gate capacitance. However, this won't eliminate the spike completely, but reduces it. A resistor is the best way, but adds a component.